# MacBook Pro recovery key has special character ($)

Tags: recovery

Hi people so I am trying to recover access to my MacBook pro however my recovery key has a special character in it the Dollar sign ($). I can’t seem to get the keyboard to type the character or any other special characters. Would anyone have an idea of how I can go about getting the dollar sign

Comment: What happens when you press Shift - 4 ?

Comment: I just the the number 4

Comment: And if you press Shift - f, what is shown?

Comment: Actually I am wrong Shift - 4 renders nothing and Shift - f renders an uppercase F

Comment: And if you press the key for numeral "4" alone (that is, _without_ the Shift key) what appears ?

Comment: I get the  number 4

Comment: I originally wondered if either the "4" key or the "Shift" key function was impaired, but your report shows that both keys misbehave, but do so inconsistently. I'm sorry, but I'm out of suggestions.

Comment: To be clear: I assume you're using the MacBook Pro's built-in keyboard, and not an external keyboard. Is this correct? If you are using an external keyboard, try a different external keyboard and a different cable as well.